# JsonProperty will serialize but not deserialize

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, rest-assured

In short, I am attempting to write an integration test with rest-assured for a rest service I wrote. My issue is that when the server attempts to deserialize the JSON I get the error with field "meta-data" not marked as ignorable. I must process this field, which also means (to the best of my knowledge) I cannot mark it as ignorable. Yes, I have "turned it off and on again". Turned off apache, manually deleted my war and exploded files, redeployed, examined the contents to see updates, turned server back on.

DISCLAIMERS: If I may not upgrade versions, but I could possibly downgrade. For example, I could use Jackson 1.0 instead of Jackson 2.0. I have also simplified my problem for sake of brevity. I can't change the JSON structure in any way. I've seen a similar Thread related to Spring, but I'm not using Spring.

This is just a fragment of the whole JSON object. If I can get meta-data and its two attributes working, I can apply what I learned to the rest of the problem. Thanks!

My JSON

```
{
  "meta-data" : {
    "submission-time" : "06.12.2016",
    "workflow-reference" : "TEST-WORKFLOW"
  }
}
```

My JSON POJO

```
package com.company.group.project.module.shared.json;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat.Feature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import java.util.List;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JsonMandateRequest {

    @JsonProperty("meta-data")
    private MetaData metadata;

    public MetaData getMetadata() {
        if (null == metadata) {
            metadata = new MetaData();
        }
        return metadata;
    }

    public void setMetadata(final MetaData metadata) {
        this.metadata = metadata;
    }

    @JsonSerialize
    public static class MetaData {

        @JsonProperty("submission-time")
        private String timestamp;

        @JsonProperty("workflow-reference")
        private String workflow;

        public String getTimestamp() {
            return timestamp;
        }

        public void setTimestamp(final String timestamp) {
            this.timestamp = timestamp;
        }

        public String getWorkflow() {
            return workflow;
        }

        public void setWorkflow(final String workflow) {
            this.workflow = workflow;
        }

    }
}
```

My Rest Service declaration (I know the path works. That is not what is broken.)

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public Response uploadFile(final JsonMandateRequest reminders) {
    return buildResponse(reminders, PROCESSOR_UPLOAD_MANDATE);
}
```

Here is the code that produces my JSON string. It works, but I'm including it in case it benefits the reader in some way.

```
public static String writeObject(final Object obj) throws IOException
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper = mapper.disable(
            DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_INVALID_SUBTYPE);
    return mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(obj);
}
```

My Integration Test code snippet

```
    Response r = given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(jsonString)
            .when().post(url);
    System.out.println("Response from " + url + "(" + r.getStatusCode() + ")");
    System.out.println(r.asString());
```

Output:

```
Response from http://localhost:8080/application/rest/path(400)
Unrecognized field "meta-data" (Class com.company.group.project.module.shared.json.JsonMandateRequest), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@b60721a; line: 2, column: 18] (through reference chain: com.company.group.project.module.shared.json.JsonMandateRequest["meta-data"])
Completed com.company.group.project.module.services.rest.InstructionServiceIT#testLifecycle(InstructionServiceIT.java:95)
```

My servlet container is tomcat 7.0.73
Here are snippets from my pom.xml which show the other versions of software I'm using.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This may be as simple as removing the jersey-json provider. The jackson-jaxrs-json-provider will register the jackson provider. This may be a jersey version mismatch problem.

Comment: You may need to register the com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider manually after you remove the jersy-json dependency.

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw Thank you! It was a version mismatch problem.

Comment: Hey Chris, I'd like to give you some credit, but I don't know how since you posted a comment, not an answer.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. Thats what it is all about. I'll upvote your answer since you figured out the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Chris Hinshaw for pointing me in the right direction. The version of jersey I'm using doesn't support the version of Jackson I'm using. I cannot step up to a newer version of Jersey, so I had to step down from Jackson 2 to Jackson 1.
I left the old stuff commented out for the benefit of the reader.

```
  <!--<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.4</version>
  </dependency>-->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Apparently, Jersey 1.9.1 is compatible with Jackson 1.9.0, at least in my case.

My new imports in JsonMandateRequest look like this.

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
```

Hope this helps someone!